# how can i launch chrome using selenium web driver in python not as a guest but as my chrome profile?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-devtools-protocol

I do the following

```js
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/bagher/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1') #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service,options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

But i get the error:

```css
    unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
      (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
      (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

does anybody know how can i fix this error?
more than 2 month i have issued this problem

first in java and i have to migrated to python
now in python i still have this problem
does anybody in this world can help me?
i am really tired

Comment: What is your OS version 10 or 11? What version of ChromeDriver are you using? Do you close your browser before running the script? Also try running your ide or console not as admin and then run the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the bug and succeeded.
[bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWbnK.png)
So what caused the accident？
When the User Data directory is used in the code, if Chrome has been opened, it will prompt that the directory is occupied.

Therefore, check whether you have manually opened a Chrome corresponding to the User Data directory when you run your code.